# For Each on Mulesoft for XMLs

Tags: xml, foreach, mulesoft

I am trying to use the for-each block on mulesoft to iterate on the node Node3a but seems to not work.  Any idea on how I can achieve this?

```html
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<Node1>
 <Node2 BEGIN="1">
  <Node3 SEGMENT="1">
   <Field>Main 1</Field>
   <Node3a SEGMENT="1">
    <Field3a1>Test 1</Field3a1>
    <Field3a2>Test 2</Field3a2>
   </Node3a>
   <Node3a SEGMENT="1">
    <Field3a1>Test 3</Field3a1>
    <Field3a2>Test 4</Field3a2>
   </Node3a>
   <Node3a SEGMENT="1">
    <Field3a1>Test 5</Field3a1>
    <Field3a2>Test 6</Field3a2>
   </Node3a>
  </Node3>
 </Node2>
</Node1>
```

Comment: Which Mule version are you using? Please show us your flow as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

try putting #[payload.Node1.Node2.Node3 - "Field"] in for each collection field.like below image. it is working for me.

[like below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tllI7.png)